# Angular - Unable to download a zip file

Tags: angular, iis

I have an angular application which is working as expected except to the ability to download a zip file from network path.

I'm getting the following error message:
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file://IPAddress/d$/***/Output.zip' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

Here is the function which I'm using to download the zip file:

```html
downloadFile(filePath: string) {
    return this.http.get(filePath, {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }).subscribe(data => {
      const blob = new Blob([data], {
        type: 'application/zip'
      });
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(url);
    });
  }
```

It is important to indicate, that by hosting the angular application on IIS 8.5, I'm facing the same issue too. Here is the web.config file that belongs to the Angular application in IIS 8.5:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/ApplicationName/"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Can you please assist in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a CORS problem.

IIS needs to send the Header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Maybe this helps for enabling it in IIS:
https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html

Comment: Hi. Thank you for you reply, but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Hi again, I modified the description of the issue. Can you please take a look?